# What Regex will match on pairs of comma-separated numbers, with pairs separated by pipes?

Tags: python, regex

I am currently trying to RegEx match (in Python) on inputs that look like:

```
37.1000,-88.1000
37.1000,-88.1000|37.1450,-88.1060
37.1000,-88.1000|37.1450,-88.1060|35.1450,-83.1060
```

So, pairs of decimal numbers, separate by commas, and then those pairs (if > 1 pair) separated by `|`. I've tried a few things but cannot seem to get a regex string that matches properly.

Attempt 1:

```
((((\d*\.?\d+,\d*\.?\d+)\|)+)|(\d*\.?\d+,\d*\.?\d+))
```

Attempt 2:

```
((((-?\d*\.?\d+,-?\d*\.?\d+)\|)+)|(-?\d*\.?\d+,-?\d*\.?\d+))
```

I was hoping someone might have done this before, or has enough RegEx experience to do something like this.

Comment: What is the expected output ? Get all pairs ?

Comment: You might just use split ()

Comment: Do you want separate matches or match the whole string?

Comment: Matching the whole string would be most useful (I think). I want to detect that the string is of that format (using RegEx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match the whole string, you could match the decimal and repeat the pattern prepended by a comma.

Then use that same pattern and repeat that prepended by a `|`

```
^[+-]?\d+\.\d+(?:,[+-]?\d+\.\d+)*(?:\|[+-]?\d+\.\d+(?:,[+-]?\d+\.\d+)*)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[+-]?\d+\.\d+` Match an optional `+` or `-` and a decimal part
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `,[+-]?\d+\.\d+` Match the same pattern as before prepended by a comma
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\|` Match `|`
  - `[+-]?\d+\.\d+` Match an optional `+` or `-` and a decimal part
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `,[+-]?\d+\.\d+` Match the same pattern as before prepended by a comma
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DmFXrs/1)

Answer (score 3):

This is what parsers are for (checking the correct format, that is):

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar

data = """
37.1000,-88.1000
37.1000,-88.1000|37.1450,-88.1060
37.1000,-88.1000|37.1450,-88.1060|35.1450,-83.1060
"""

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    line    = pair (pipe pair)*
    pair    = point ws? comma ws? point
    point   = ~"-?\d+(?:.\d+)?"
    comma   = ","
    pipe    = "|"
    ws      = ~"\s+"
    """
)


for line in data.split("\n"):
    try:
        grammar.parse(line)
        print("Correct format: {}".format(line))
    except:
        print("Not correct: {}".format(line))
```

This will yield

```
Not correct: 
Correct format: 37.1000,-88.1000
Correct format: 37.1000,-88.1000|37.1450,-88.1060
Correct format: 37.1000,-88.1000|37.1450,-88.1060|35.1450,-83.1060
Not correct:
```

Bot `Not correct:` statements come from the empty lines.

---

If you actually want to retrieve the values, you'd need to write another `Visitor` class:

```
class Points(NodeVisitor):
    grammar = Grammar(
        r"""
        line    = pair (pipe pair)*
        pair    = point ws? comma ws? point
        point   = ~"-?\d+(?:.\d+)?"
        comma   = ","
        pipe    = "|"
        ws      = ~"\s+"
        """
    )

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_pair(self, node, visited_children):
        x, *_, y = visited_children
        return (x.text, y.text)

    def visit_line(self, node, visited_children):
        pairs = [visited_children[0]]
        for potential_pair in [item[1] for item in visited_children[1]]:
            pairs.append(potential_pair)
        return pairs

point = Points()
for line in data.split("\n"):
    try:
        pairs = point.parse(line)
        print(pairs)
    except ParseError:
        print("Not correct: {}".format(line))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need regex for this. Keep it simple.

### Step 1

Split on `,`.

```
s.split(',')
```

### Step 2

Split on `|` and ensure each result is of type `float` (rather, that it can be converted to this type without fault). The second step here (validation) can be removed if it's not required.

```
r = s.split('|')
for v in r:
    try:
        float(v)
    except ValueError:
        print(v + ' is not a float')
```

### Step 3

Combine.

[Test it here](https://tio.run/##jZDNCsIwEITPyVPsLS1WqdSfUvDoK3gRKbGmWmiTsomi0HevSVoFxYOnhJlvJ5NtH@aiZNL32mAlzxo2sKeEJevZPI7jaJqm/sKiH2LnhMXyJaz@pLpk@RKSYYweKD2JEnRbVyZXMi9U0/BAhxklKMwVJeiZNwMWsfALPnIcUVv@zXWWI6VCuEElAa1NDD7cQcpacRPcrE/EvRCtgR2vr2KLqDxHWrsKC8AEGFQapDLAwU@50LERUuritYsfl5cNLxZe@vGXMfijeRGGff8E)

```
strings = [
    '37.1000,-88.1000',
    '37.1000,-88.1000|37.1450,-88.1060',
    '37.1000,-88.1000|37.1450,-88.1060|35.1450,-83.1060'
]

def split_on_comma(s):
    return s.split(',')

def split_on_bar(s):
    r = s.split('|')
    for v in r:
        try:
            float(v)
        except ValueError:
            print(v + ' is not a float')
    return r

for s in strings:
    for c in split_on_comma(s):
        print(split_on_bar(c))
```

---

Without validation and functions, your code becomes:

```
for s in strings:
    for c in s.split(','):
        for b in c.split('|'):
            print(b)
```

---

You can change the output to your liking, but this presents each required step for splitting and validating the data.

Comment: True (and +1) but you could even use your Porsche to pick up some milk...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the value by pairs, and you use a simple regex or just `split()`

```
for value in values:
    pairs = re.findall("([\d. ,-]+)\|?", value)
    for pair in pairs:
        v1, v2 = pair.strip().split(",")
# or
for value in values:
    pairs = value.split("|")
    for pair in pairs:
        v1, v2 = pair.strip().split(",")
```